# how to display rows associated with logged-in users

Tags: mysql, join, authorization, cakephp-3.0

I have just started learning cakephp3, so please excuse me for anything wrong. So I have three tables called Users, Projects and Events, so there relation is like, one user can hasmany projects and one project can has many events.

if i access the basic url

> testap/events

I want only those events to appear in the list which belongs to the logged-in user.
Note: Event table has only project id not user id and project table has user id.

Consider the following scenarios

Projcts Table

```
ID User_id
1 1
2 1
3 2
4 3
```

Events Table

```
ID Project_id
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 2
6 3
7 4
```

So I want only to display events 1to5 as they belong to the logged-in user (say user with id 1 has logged in)

Please tell how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This should help you https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

Comment: He said cake 3. This would likely be a better option [Retrieving Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new cake 3 orm is fantastic for something like this.

```
// You can replace $this->Users with TableRegistry::get('users') 
// if not in the users controller
$user = $this->Users->find($this->Auth->user('id'), [
    'contain' => [
        'Projects.Events'
    ]
]);
```

You can get your events like this

```
$user->projects[0]->events;
```

Or if you get want to get events for a specific user you can do it backwards

```
$events = $this->Events->find()->matching('Projects.Users', function ($query) use ($userId) {
    return $query->where(['user_id' => $userId]);
});
```

I am assuming you have defined in your UsersTable initialize function

```
$this->hasMany('Projects');
```

And in your ProjectsTable

```
$this->hasMany('Events');
$this->belongsTo('Users');
```

And in your events table

```
$this->belongsTo('Projects');
```